# Why I'm unable to install application in my phone. Redmi 7s Connected already but it's not showing to install application in Android Studio. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build

Android Studio Not Showing My Phone for Run Application:

[image: Android Studio Not Showing My Phone for Run Application - ScreenShot]

I want to run my developed application directly on my phone but I'm unable to run this. Because It's not showing in android studio. It also not working on emulator also. I already ready Google Development Guidelines(https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html).  But these are not working for my system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Developer mode on your phone?
If you haven't done yet follow these steps:

- Go to settings -> About phone.
- Tap on Build number 7 times and the developer option will be on.

If you have already enabled it then:

- Go to Settings and find Developer options.
- Check whether it is enabled or not.
- Swipe down and find USB debugging. This option should be enabled. (Also enable Wireless ADB debugging if you're running app wirelessly)

Comment: I'm already using Android Studio from the Last three years. So, it's already enabled and I have checked again. I'm getting the same problem after updating Android Studio.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the 'Default USB configuration'. Try selecting 'No data transfer' in this option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer

I am also facing this issue couple of month ago, I had checked that I had enabled the USB debugging in developer but there is an issue with the Redmi phones that along with the USB debugging you will need to do the following

**Go To Settings > Additional Settings > Developer Options**

1. Enable USB debugging
2. Enable Install via USB
3. Disable Turn on MIUI optimization
4. On Select USB configuration select MIDI or File transfer (this is 
   what solved the problem for me)

also, keep in mind to give an RSA permission

you also check the link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device?hl=ro

Comment: The same one I already read in Android Studio "Turbleshoot Device Connection" and tried already. But it's not working. I thought it's ADB Problem so I try to update ADB in Windows 10 then also it's showing Window already Updated Your ADB. I have two phones I have tried both but both are not working. Second, think when I try to install the application in empulator then also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem on my own. The problem was in Android SDK. I'm using 2 windows in my same pc so I just used android studio on my another window then it's was working perfectly so I thought i have to try with changes that windows Android/Sdk folder in other windows which one I had problem. So I just copy (C:\Users{MyUserName}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk) in getting the problem window and try again the android studio & Wawu... It's starting working. I hope it's will be helpful for you also.